# for(i=0;0;i ) in c executes exactly one time why?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

```
for(i=0; 0; i)
{
    //statement
}
```

Why the statement executes only one time ? Either it does not execute the statement or the statement should go into an infinite loop. but the statement executes just one time. Can you please help me.

Comment: Since condition `0` is false, it should not execute the loop body.

Comment: the loop shouldn't execute even once

Comment: Executing on my machine, the for loop is not even entered. I am using GCC on Linux.

Comment: You are likely misidentifying something else as the statement execution, or perhaps you are linking in an old version of the object file that your compiler built before you changed the source code.

Comment: Is this the exact code you have? Do you by any chance have `for(i=0;0;i);{/*loop body*/}`?

Comment: @KapilGarg: what platform/compiler are you using? How did you determine that the `//statement` line executed once?

Comment: It was the extra semicolon @Dan mentioned, as the OP confirmed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356326/fori-00i-in-c-executes-exactly-one-time-why/18014145#comment16592658_12356393).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you don't have a semi-colon after the for loop otherwise the compiler will take the semi-colon to be the end of the loop and anything in the following braces will be executed once.

```
for(i=0; 0; i); // end of loop

{
   // do something once
}
```

You don't have a semicolon in your example but I've seen people do this often in programming courses and the fact it runs once is a symptom of this mistake. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Good point, this common typo-bug would present as if the loop executed once.

Comment: It was actually this, as the OP confirmed in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356326/fori-00i-in-c-executes-exactly-one-time-why/18014145#comment16592658_12356393).

Answer (score 5):

Actually, that line will not execute the statement.  I would look at your program again to see if some other output / statements have been misidentified as the output of the statement in the block

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int i;
  for (i = 0; 0; i) {
    printf("i is %d\n", i);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

when ran yields no output.

Another possibility is that your source code is now out-of-sync with your binaries, something that happens occasionally with hand rolled C build systems.  Try removing your `.o` object files, your generated binaries, and recompiling from scratch.  If the execution disappears, perhaps you need to look at how you achieve your build a bit more carefully.

Answer (score 1):

This is quote from the C99 standard about the for loop:

> ```
> 6.8.5.3 The for statement 1 The statement
> ```
>
> for ( clause-1 ; expression-2 ; expression-3 )
>
> statement behaves as follows: The expression expression-2 is the
> controlling expression that is evaluated before each execution of the
> loop body. The expression expression-3 is evaluated as a void
> expression after each execution of the loop body. If clause-1 is a
> declaration, the scope of any variables it declares is the remainder
> of the declaration and the entire loop, including the other two
> expressions; it is reached in the order of execution before the first
> evaluation of the controlling expression. If clause-1 is an
> expression, it is evaluated as a void expression before the first
> evaluation of the controlling expression.134)

Since the condition is false, it shouldn't execute it even once. So it's clearly a bug in the compiler you use.

Comment: Before to affirm there is a bug in a compiler, we should see the real code.

Comment: @dystroy I assumed OP compiled the same code that's posted with no additional functionality. This is a known issue in the turbo C compiler which I suspect is the one used by OP.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

then lookup the for loop on google.
There are three parts to a for loop

**initialization ; loop end condition ; increment.**

why your code says, is probably not what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

This loop will not execute even one time because the terminating condition is 0 ie false

```
for(i=0; 0; i)
{
  printf("%d",&i)
}
```

Does not print any thing.

Comment: Ok guys.. m very very sorry.. actually there was semicolon after end of for loop